# I want to find the top 3 rank of customers based on value of cash in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

For a customer i need to find out the rank value based on the cash value

**Input**

Id No      prob
   1     0.000000
   1     0.000000
   1     0.000000
   1     0.000000
   1     0.000000
   1     0.000000
   3     0.000000
   3     0.000000
  2748   0.43668
  2354    0.43616

**output**

Id No      prob      rank

```
1     0.000000      15
1     0.000000      15
1     0.000000      15
1     0.000000      15
1     0.000000      15
1     0.000000      15
3     0.000000      10
3     0.000000      10
```

2748   0.43668        1
   2354   0.43616        1

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: prob  Id No  rank
3       0.000000      1    15
4       0.000000      1    15
6       0.000000      1    15
8       0.000000      1    15
9       0.000000      1    15
10      0.000000      1    15
16      0.000000      3    10
18      0.000000      3    10
20      0.000000      3    10
21      0.000000      3    10
28      0.000000      4    10
30      0.000000      4    10
32      0.000000      4    10
33      0.000000      4    10
35      0.719424      6    46
36      0.961538      6    47
37      0.000000      6    21

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.rank.html) with `ascending=False` and casting to integers:

```
df['rank'] = df.groupby('Cust_id')['cash'].rank(ascending=False).astype(int)
print (df)
   Cust_id Things   cash  rank
0        1    bag  25000     1
1        1    tag   5000     2
2        1     bg   2000     3
3        2    pen   5000     2
4        2    pet   4000     3
5        2    red   7000     1
```

Comment: prob      Id No  rank
3       0.000000      1    15
4       0.000000      1    15
6       0.000000      1    15
8       0.000000      1    15
9       0.000000      1    15
10      0.000000      1    15
16      0.000000      3    10
18      0.000000      3    10
20      0.000000      3    10
21      0.000000      3    10
28      0.000000      4    10
30      0.000000      4    10
32      0.000000      4    10
33      0.000000      4    10
35      0.719424      6    46
36      0.961538      6    47
37      0.000000      6    21

Comment: for this data after grouping it is not ranking it in the correct order

Comment: @raj - Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60861990/edit) question with new data, because bad format of data in comments? also pleas add expected output. Thanks.

Comment: I tried the same code u have gave but the result is not as expected

Comment: @raj - Why there is `15`? `10`? What is expected output from only data can see in question? I think only groups `1, 3, 2748 and 2354 `